# Using Hashcat to load a compressed wordlist

Tags: hashing

after researching a little bit i was able to find out that this is possible, but the people who were able to accomplish this didn't really post an example or command line to do so...
The title says it all, in case i need to elaborate all of this:
My problem is that i have a 140gb Compressed wordlist which is around 4gb After being compressed. Now i do not have enough disk space , so was wondering if i can somehow load the compressed file to hashcat and it seems that it might be possible to do so...
Help a fellow cracker out guys!
:)

Comment: Tried every possible command do not know what to do lol!!

Comment: hello?? 4 days no answer

Answer (score 3):

As of [Hashcat 6.0.0](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/blob/ba2746228a40ebeed53a187dfa54fc6154234481/docs/changes.txt#L14), wordlists compressed as .gz or .zip are now detected and decompressed on the fly.

> Support on-the-fly loading of compressed wordlists in zip and gzip format

For versions of hashcat older than 6.0.0, you can do this by decompressing to `stdout` and then piping it to hashcat (but it will be slower than the equivalent direct file reads):

```
$ gunzip -cd myfile.gz | hashcat -a 0 [arguments]
```

Comment: How does piping the decompressed wordlist into hashcat affect the initial step of "Dictionary cache building"?

Comment: Good question. If you're piping, hashcat doesn't know where the input is coming from, so it can't cache it as a dictionary. So you're better off bumping up to hashcat 6+ and taking advantage of the native decompression.